# Why this derived class is not a standard layout class?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

Why `bar` is not a standard layout type, under C++17?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

class foo {
    int x;
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<foo>::value);

class bar : public foo {
    float y;
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<bar>::value); // "static assertion failed"
```

Based on [CPP Reference description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) and [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900421/why-is-this-struct-not-standard-layout) I understand why this is not a standard layout type until C++14, but am unable to connect [CPP reference's description item](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) that, by excluding everything else, should be the one applying here: "None of the base class subobjects has the same type as
for non-union types, as the first non-static data member (see empty base optimization), and, recursively, the first non-static data member of that data member if it has non-union class type, or all non-static data members of that data member if it has union type, or an element of that data member if it has array type, etc."

Comment: We don't put the answer in the question.

Comment: I don't get why the original "excluding everything else" part should be restored when it's actively misleading because I managed to miss the applying item, but it's not a big deal I guess

Comment: Your question exists *because* you "excluded everything else". If you take that away, then there is no question.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bar` does not fulfill the requirement before the one you quoted (from [cppreference.com page on standard layout classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType)):

> **Requirements**:
>
> - [...]
> - Has all non-static data members and bit-fields declared in the same class (either all in the derived or all in some base)
> - [...]

`bar` has a direct non-static data member `float y;` and an inherited non-static data member `int x;` from `foo`.

---

The wording since C++14 of this particular requirement is (for the most part?) functionally equivalent to the one from before and that was also mentioned in the answer to the question you linked.

It was changed only because of a potential for misunderstanding in the wording, see [CWG issue 1813](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1813) and bit-fields were added to it because they might have not been included in the term *members*, see [CWG issue 1881](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1881).